# How do I deserialize a namespaced element to an object in .net?

Tags: .net, serialization

Given this XML snippet:

```
...
<InSide:setHierarchyUpdates>
   <automaticUpdateInterval>5</automaticUpdateInterval>
   <shouldRunAutomaticUpdates>true<shouldRunAutomaticUpdates>
</InSide:setHierarchyUpdates>
...
```

I am attempting to serialize this object:

```
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
<XmlRoot(ElementName:="setHierarchyUpdates", namespace:="InSide")> _
Public Class HierarchyUpdate
    <XmlElement(ElementName:="shouldRunAutomaticUpdates")> _
    Public shouldRunAutomaticUpdates As Boolean
    <XmlElement(ElementName:="automaticUpdateInterval")> _
      Public automaticUpdateInterval As Integer
End Class
```

Like this:

```
Dim hierarchyUpdater As New HierarchyUpdate
Dim x As New XmlSerializer(hierarchyUpdater.GetType)
Dim objReader As Xml.XmlNodeReader = New Xml.XmlNodeReader(myXMLNode)
hierarchyUpdater = x.Deserialize(objReader)
```

However, the object, after deserialization, has values of false and zero.  If I switch the objReader to a streamreader and read this in as a file, with none of its parents and no namespaces, it works:

```
<setHierarchyUpdates>
   <automaticUpdateInterval>5</automaticUpdateInterval>
   <shouldRunAutomaticUpdates>true<shouldRunAutomaticUpdates>
</setHierarchyUpdates>
```

What am I doing wrong?  Should I use something other than XMLRoot in the class definition, because, as an XML node, it's not really the root?  If so, what?  Why are no errors returned when this fails?

Answer (score 2):

Just simply specify the default namespace to use in your call to the XmlSerializer constructor:

```
Dim hierarchyUpdater As New HierarchyUpdate
Dim x As New XmlSerializer(hierarchyUpdater.GetType, "http://yournamespace.org")
Dim objReader As Xml.XmlNodeReader = New Xml.XmlNodeReader(myXMLNode)
hierarchyUpdater = x.Deserialize(objReader)
```

Note: the `InSide` you're using is most probably only the XML namespace prefix - not the real XML namespace. Somewhere in your XML document, you should see a definition something like:

```
xmlns:InSide="http://yournamespace.org"
```

(or something similar) - you need to use the actual namespace - not the prefix - in the XmlSerializer constructor call

Comment: Thank you for the note about the namespace prefix.  However, even when I add the namespace to the constructor (ensuring that it is not just the prefix) - it still does not deserialize correctly.

I don't think this would change things, but the parent element (above shouldRunAutomaticUpdates) has multiple namespaces defined, one of which is 'InSide'.